# Vue prop not updating properly in a child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-reactivity, vue-props

I've got a child component that receives a prop from the parent component. I've added an event to update the prop in the parent component when a button is clicked. But the child component does not detect the prop change.

Approximate code:

Parent component:

```
<template>
  <table>
    <Student v-for="(student, index) in students"
      :key="index"
      :student="student"
      :attendance="attendance[student.id]"
      @attended-clicked="changeAttendance"
    ></student>
  </table>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        students: [
          {id: 1, name: 'Pepito'},
          {id: 2, name: 'Sue'},
        ],
        attendance: {
          1: {attended: true},
          2: {attended: false},
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      changeAttendance(studentId) {
        this.attendance[studentId].attended = !this.attendance[studentId].attended;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Child component:

```
<template>
  <tr>
    <td>{{ student.name }}</td>
    <td><v-btn :color="attendance.attended ? 'green' : 'red'"
          @click="$emit('attended-clicked', student.id)"
        >Attended</v-btn>
  </tr>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['student', 'attendance']
  }
</script>
```

I've tried to keep the code as minimal as possible to give you an idea of what I'm trying to achieve. The expectation is that when the button is clicked, `attendance.attended` will change.

I can verify that the value is changing when clicked using Vue developer tools (although I have to press the "force refresh" button to see the change). But apparently the child view is not picking up on the change.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here that's breaking reactivity?

I've also tried using `Vue.set` with some code like this:

```
methods: {
  changeAttendance(studentId) {
    let attendance = this.attendance[studentId];
    attendance.attended = !attendance.attended;
    Vue.set(this.attendance, studentId, attendance);
  }
}
```

No difference.

I appreciate any insight into what I'm doing wrong, thanks!

Comment: can you make a snippet

Comment: Not sure how to make a snippet with multiple vue components and vuetify. I'll look into it though

Comment: `students` and `attendance` should be a array i guess

Comment: @Chris Is this what you need: https://s8o8q.csb.app/?

Comment: Functionality-wise. The styling can be changed

Comment: Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-mayer-s8o8q)

Comment: `data` should be a function. @Chris. It should return `students` and `attendance` properties. I expect an error to be thrown for that, unless it's a typo?

Comment: Is `tempate` a typo in the question or your code?

Comment: Thanks for the sandbox example, @MarsNebulaSoup! I'll make sure to provide examples like this for future questions. The important thing here is that you've shown me that props work they way I expect them to. I think the problem I'm having then is actually that the attendance data comes from an API call and is set to `{}` originally. When updated from the API call I think it loses its reactivity or something...

Comment: Sure. Besides the typos, [the code](https://s8o8q.csb.app) seems to work like you want, does it not?

Comment: Thanks guys for pointing out the some of the typos in my examples. I didn't have them in my actual code though

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments, the underlying problem is that `attendance` gets set to `{}`, meaning the `attendance[student.id]` objects are not really there or not being tracked anymore according to the [change detection part in the VueJS docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/change-detection.html#for-objects). This is what should be done by the `Vue.set` example code provided in the question.

Basically I see two options how to solve this:

1. Set attendance to always have all students ids available when the API returns a result, making the object always have an already working object
2. Start tracking the reactivity when you need to get a value from `attendance`.

Since I don't know about the API and how it's being called, I'll provide an answer for option 2. The provided code almost worked, it only needs two changes to the `Parent` component to make sure the students attendance object is always filled and it will get tracked in the future:

```
<template>
  <table>
    <!-- :attendance needs an object to work -->
    <Student
      v-for="(student, index) in students"
      :key="index"
      :student="student"
      :attendance="attendance[student.id] || {}"
      @attended-clicked="changeAttendance"
    />
  </table>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from "vue";
import StudentVue from "./Student.vue";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      students: [{ id: 1, name: "Pepito" }, { id: 2, name: "Sue" }],
      attendance: {}
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeAttendance(studentId) {
      // make sure to have an object when accessing a student!
      let attendance = this.attendance[studentId] || {};
      attendance.attended = !attendance.attended;
      // start tracking - this will always "reset" the tracking though!
      Vue.set(this.attendance, studentId, attendance);
    }
  },
  components: { Student: StudentVue }
};
</script>
```

Since `this.attendance[student.id] || {}` is being used multiple times, I'd capsulate this into a `getAttendance(studentId) {...}` function though. In there, `Vue.set` could be used to start tracking if the object did not exist before, making `changeAttendance` a bit simpler and the intention of this `|| {}` more clear.

```
<template>
  <table>
    <Student
      v-for="(student, index) in students"
      :key="index"
      :student="student"
      :attendance="getAttendance(student.id)"
      @attended-clicked="changeAttendance"
    />
  </table>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from "vue";
import StudentVue from "./Student.vue";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      students: [{ id: 1, name: "Pepito" }, { id: 2, name: "Sue" }],
      attendance: {}
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeAttendance(studentId) {
      let attendance = this.getAttendance(studentId);
      attendance.attended = !attendance.attended;
    },
    getAttendance(studentId) {
      const studentAttendance = this.attendance[studentId];
      if (!studentAttendance) {
        Vue.set(this.attendance, studentId, { attended: false });
      }
      return this.attendance[studentId];
    }
  },
  components: { Student: StudentVue }
};
</script>
```

If the code base is using `this.something[something]` in other components, the `this.getAttendance` might look a bit inconsistent. In that case, it's probably better to change the result of the API call to all students with a default for them before feeding it to the `Parent` component then. Personally, I'd try to use that option. And I'd use `this.$set` instead of `Vue.set` to get rid of the `import Vue` line... ;)