# Props changes in parent do not update child

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I'm new to using VueJS and am trying to work out how update/re-render a child component when props change in it's parent.

I originally pass an empty array into the child - then, after sending a dispatch in the Vuex store, I pass the updated data into the array. I'm expecting to see the child update when this happens but there is no change, the updated() method is also not called within the child.

Parent component:

```
<template>
  <div class="loginPanel">
    <div className="col">
      <BaseSelect
        v-model="this.sourceGroup"
        :options="this.groupCodeList"
        label="Source Group"
        :emit-event="'sourceGroupSelected'"
        @sourceGroupSelected="sourceGroupSelected"
      />
    </div>
    <div className="col mt-4">
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import BaseSelect from './BaseSelect'
export default {
  name: 'SelectSourceGroup',
  components: { BaseSelect },
  props: {},
  data() {
    return {
      selectedSourceGroup: '',
      sourceGroup: '',
      groupCodeList: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sourceGroupSelected(value) {
      console.log(value)
    },
  },
  computed: {
    groupCodes() {
      return this.$store.state.groupCodes
    },
  },
  created() {
    if (!this.$store.state.groupCodes) {
      this.$store.dispatch('getAllGroupCodes')
    }
  },
  updated() {
    if (this.groupCodeList.length < 1) {
      for (const group of this.groupCodes) {
        const { group_code, group_name } = group
        this.groupCodeList.push({
          key: group_code,
          val: group_code,
          name: group_name,
        })
      }
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Child:

```
<template>
  <label v-if="label">{{ label }}</label>
  <select class="field" :value="modelValue" @change="onChange($event)">
    <option disabled v-if="label" value="">Select a {{ label }}...</option>
    <option disabled v-if="!label" value="">Select an option...</option>
    <option
      v-for="option in this.options"
      :value="option.val"
      :key="option.key"
      :selected="option.val === modelValue"
    >
      {{ option.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    label: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    modelValue: {
      type: [String, Number],
      default: '',
    },
    emitEvent: {
      type: [String],
    },
    options: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
    optionLabel: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Select an option...',
    },
  },
  updated() {
    console.log(this.options)
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(event) {
      console.log(this.emitEvent)
      this.$emit(this.emitEvent, event.target.value)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

I've also tried using Vue.set after reading here: [Vue prop not updating properly in a child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63526274/vue-prop-not-updating-properly-in-a-child-component) but this experiences the same issue, the child is not updated and the updated() function is not called:

```
updated() {
    if (this.groupCodeList.length < 1) {
      for (let x = 0; x < this.groupCodes.length; x++) {
        const { group_code, group_name } = this.groupCodes[x]

        let ind = x.toString()

        this.$set(this.groupCodeList, ind, {
          key: group_code,
          val: group_code,
          name: group_name,
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Vue.set()` or `this.$set` only work for Objects - for Arrays you need methods like `Array.push` or `Array.splice`

Comment: As you can see from my first code block, the original attempt used `this.groupCodeList.push` but didn't work

Comment: Because you are pushing inside the `updated` lifecycle hook - try to push in the `created` lifecycle hook. Or, if your data comes from Vuex - simply use a Vuex getter.

Comment: I've tried accessing `this.$store.state.groupCodes` but it evaluates to `null` (though I know the action returns the data as if I use it directly within the html I can use it). What am I doing wrong here? 

I've also tried creating a getter for this which is also null

Comment: Your action must commit a mutation which will change the Vuex state - otherwise you can simply access the action's Promise through `.then(result => { this.groupCodeList = result; })`